# cadena de texto con ciclo while python

Tags: python-3.x

Hola compañeros llevo varios dias sin poder resolver un ejercicio, tal vez para ustedes es facil pero en mi caso no he podido resolverlo.
Escriba la función list2(x) que devuelve la lista x con sus elementos elevados al cuadrado. Use un ciclo while en vez de un ciclo for o recursión para su implementación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Arcangel, procura evitar ocupar imagenes de codigo, en cambio escribe el codigo directamente en la pagina para que podamos probarlo y ejecutarlo más facilmente. Además, rotula correctamente tus referencias. En este caso, la imagen que colocas a que corresponde? Tu pregunta parece un copy-paste del ejercicio del profesor, ponle un poco mas de esfuerzo!

Comment: Tienes razón Vicente, soy nuevo en esto, la imagen hace referencia a lo que he estado haciendo para resolver el ejercicio

Comment: Bienvenido @ArcangelCataño recuerda siempre agregar el código como texto ya que en ocasiones este no es legible, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solucion que satisface los requerimientos que expones.

```
def list2(x):
  def _list(x):
    c = 0
    while c < len(x):
      yield x[c]**2
      c += 1
  return list(_list(x))

print(list2([1,2,3]))  # [1,4,9]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Vicente me sirvio mucho tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Primero define la función que reciba una lista con elementos.
Dicha función debe retornar una lista con los valores finales.

Posterior a eso, defines la lista inicial, llamas a la función y la asignas a una variable o la usas en un ciclo si lo deseas.

```
def al_cuadrado(lista):
    al_cuadrado = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(lista):
       al_cuadrado.append(lista[i]**2)
       i += 1
    return al_cuadrado

lista_inicial = [1, 6, 2, 8]
resultados = al_cuadrado(lista_inicial)

for i in resultados:
    print(i)

for i in al_cuadrado(lista_inicial):
    print(i)
```

No es necesario un contador, ya que solo debes recorrer cada uno de los elementos de la lista.

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Lee el enunciado bien, no se puede ocupar for ni recursividad. Saludos.